# Get Location Periodically Using Background Services,Save In Local Database in Android

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

1.In My application ,I want to track User Current Location Every 1 minute then Save in Local Database.**Not getting Proper location Some times ,when user is Walking**.

2.For finding location ,I want to use Google play Services API.

**My Need:**

**Background Service Should get the location, save in local Database every minute.Even Application is Closed.**

also with **low Battery Usage**.

I tried Some codes some methods are deprecated and not Working.

Please Suggest me any solution.

Comment: Just use google places API for android, its fast and easy. 

it uses http request so it won't be a problem for android

Comment: ok ,but not finding any example with background services ,Location Finding using Google Places API.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place

Comment: check this answer and inform if you stuck anywhere http://stackoverflow.com/a/34490370/2826147

Comment: check this answer its does provide you solution for background service. https://github.com/vipulasri/LocationUpdates

Comment: @VipulAsri iam trying with this Code.!

Comment: @VipulAsri this may cause the Battery? its working Good.!

Comment: @Kumar yes surely it will consume battery as it is running continuously.

Comment: @VipulAsri I want to make my App less Battery Usage and Tracking Every  1 minute location.how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way you can achieve it, make your service class like below

here,

with this **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** your service will be on in background
and you will need **LocationManager**

your **SERVICE.class** extend Service implements LocationListener, Runnable

```
    private LocationManager mgr = null;
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);



        @Override
         public void onCreate() {
                 //check gps is on/off
                 //get locationmanager
          }

         @Override
         public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                  //check if internet is on/off
                  setBeforeDelay15();
                  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
         }

         @Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                   //re-execute at time you need with **scheduleAtFixedRate**
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {
                 //here get the best location from two ways 1>gps and 2>network provider
                 //once you get this insert to database
                 //set delay then request call method  again
         }

          @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
                //if locationmanager is not null then remove all updates
          }

         private void setDelay15() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {             
                    // Log.e("srop self by", "delay15");   
                    startWork();           
                }
            }, 300000);//120000
        }

private void startWork() {
//check here for 1>gps and 2>network provider
//get location and save it
}
```

use this , when you require location in your application.